# How does Flutter calculate pixels for different resolutions?

Tags: dart, flutter

Flutter apps can run on a variety of hardware, operating systems, and form factors. How are "pixels" calculated for different resolutions?

Comment: This is a good summary of how Flutter treats screen sizes across different devices: https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-effectively-scale-ui-according-to-different-screen-sizes-2cb7c115ea0a

Answer (score 19):

From https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/FlutterView/devicePixelRatio.html :

> The number of device pixels for each logical pixel. This number might
> not be a power of two. Indeed, it might not even be an integer. For
> example, the Nexus 6 has a device pixel ratio of 3.5.
>
> Device pixels are also referred to as physical pixels. Logical pixels
> are also referred to as device-independent or resolution-independent
> pixels.
>
> By definition, there are roughly 38 logical pixels per centimeter, or
> about 96 logical pixels per inch, of the physical display. The value
> returned by devicePixelRatio is ultimately obtained either from the
> hardware itself, the device drivers, or a hard-coded value stored in
> the operating system or firmware, and may be inaccurate, sometimes by
> a significant margin.
>
> The Flutter framework operates in logical pixels, so it is rarely
> necessary to directly deal with this property.

Comment: IS their any third party plugin for text Size , margin padding spaces ?

Comment: @HarshBhavsar, have you find a plugin for text size and margin? I found flutter_screenutil, but can't make it work as I wish.There is also a good function here https://github.com/MarcinusX/bmi_calculator/blob/v0.1/lib/widget_utils.dart, but not perfect.

Comment: @David no I am targeting with one device's wh and calculating padding/margin with width and height to each screens.