# Does Flutter automatically resize elements (icons, images, etc) to fit the screen dimensions?

Tags: flutter

Just wondering, does Flutter automatically resize icons and other elements to fit the size of the screen? For example, if I set an icon size to 50px, will it look the same on an Iphone 8 vs an Iphone 8 plus? The Iphone 8 plus has a much larger screen.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44572330/how-does-flutter-calculate-pixels-for-different-resolutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you wrapped with extended widget your icons, images etc. these will be shown in original size in different platform, but it could breake your widget or your app, if you dont use extended widget.